# For vehicles with 2 or more suppliers, COUNT the number of parts (vehicle_part) and suppliers (supplier) per vehicle

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

- Data model

[image: data model]

**- Goal:**
Count the number of suppliers (supplier) and parts (vehicle_part) for each vehicle for which there are two or more suppliers.

**- requirements:**
Expected columns: `vehicle_name, vehicle_part_count, supplier_count` in that order

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Goal: Count the number of suppliers (supplier) and parts (vehicle_part) for each vehicle for which there are *two or more suppliers* <-- for each part ?

There could be like 5 parts of a vehicle so 1 supplier per part = 5 different suppliers, does that count or not ?

Comment: How I could Count the parts and suppliers for each car. as you commented 5 parts could have 5 different suppliers

Comment: Could 2 different vehicle_part_ids have same supplier ?

Comment: Indeed, there may be a part supplied by more then One Supplier

Comment: That supplier should also appear once in the count right ?

Comment: let's assume that exact behavor I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.vehicle_name, count(distinct vp.vehicle_part_id) as 
vehicle_part_count, count(distinct vps.supplier_id) as supplier_count
from vehicle_part vp 
join vehicle_part_supplier vps on 
vp.vehicle_part_id=vps.vehicle_part_id
join vehicle v on vp.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id 
group by v.vehicle_name
having count(distinct vps.supplier_id)>=2;
```